# How do i change my spinner ArrayAdapter<String> into a hashmap?

Tags: android, spinner

How do i change my spinner from string into a hashmap? I am getting my data in spinner from my database using json. I want to pass by id everytime a select a spinner data. The problem is i dont know how to change my spinner into a hashmap. Help me pls. Thank you!

Here is my spinner

```
 final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
 spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);

  ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(0);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Basketball.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
```

Here is how i add data to my spinner

```
try
        {
            URL url = new URL (Config.URL_SPIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json;

            s_name = new String[JA.length()];
            s_gender = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
            {
                json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
                s_gender[i] =  json.getString("s_gender");
                s_name[i]   =  json.getString("s_name");
            }
            list1.add("All");
            for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        spinner_fn();


    }
```

Comment: Create your own custom adapter class.

Comment: Another class? i will put everything there sir, the retrieving of data?

Comment: No you don't need to put everything there.

Comment: You want ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> instead of ArrayAdapter<String>?

Comment: yes sir, is that possible when i am getting my data in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use hashmap with arrayadapter you need list with hashmap type:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And pass this list to your adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
```

hope this may helps you.

Comment: I am having problem here sir  list1.add("All");
            for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
            }

Comment: says List cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)

Comment: Switch to List<Object>, otherwise you are going to have some hard time dealing with generic boxing and unboxing rules. Switching to List<Object> would allow you to both add Strings and HashMap. The answer given by Piyush is pretty close to what you want

Comment: You have to add hashmap instead of string. Just one quick question why do you need to use hashmap particularly?

Comment: to pass id taken from my database to the next activity sir, I have a code on how to pass it by hashmap. I just dont know how to change string into hasmap

Comment: working now, can i pass a hashmap in my spinner? example this  HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String news_id = map.get(Config.TAG_news_id).toString();
                        String title = map.get(Config.TAG_title).toString();
                        String content = map.get(Config.TAG_content).toString();